# Magento 2 : How to use Modal Slide for CRUD Operation using custom module in Admin side?

Tags: magento2.3, modal

I am trying to create a CRUD operation using Modal Slide in Magento 2 Admin Area like below.

Please refer the below screenshot.

[image]

I'm spending the last 3 days on this.
Please assist if anybody knows about this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: any one have an idea

Comment: anybody there to answer

Comment: anybody there to help on this

Comment: Did you find the solution on how to create a CRUD in magento 2.3?